# Comparing data sets for simularity

Tags: statistics, compare

I am doing an experiment in which three sets of measurements are recorded in a cold, comfortable and hot environment. I would like to compare the similarity of the three sets but I do not know which statistical method is suitable. I thinking about using a [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) or [MinHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash)but I am not sure what is the best approach to solving this. Can someone give any suggestion of any statistical method that is used to compare two or more non-linear datasets?